# syncfusion_flutter_charts not provide all my data

Tags: flutter, syncfusion-chart

I am trying to use this chart package and retrieve the data from firebase
the data is added by the user for example if Alex added 300 then added 400 I will add to the firebase tow different document one for 300 and one for 400 like in this photo all of these document for one user
[image]

So, I want to retrieve all of the values and dates from all document for every user and provide chart with these information
note : my application is linking the elderly user with his watcher the elderly user will add his glucose value from his home and the chart will displayed in the watcher home this is my code which goes correctly but I am only having one column in my chart I tried to print the list length and it give me 4 which equals the number of document

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future getElderlyId() async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
          .get()
          .then((data) {
        setState(() {
          elderlyId = data.data()['elderlyId'];
        });
      });
    }

return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('glucose')
            .where('uid', isEqualTo: elderlyId)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          final doc = snapshot.data.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 1,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                List<ChartData> chartData = <ChartData>[];
                for (int i = 1; i <= doc.length; i++) {
                  chartData.add(
                      ChartData(doc[index]['date'], doc[index]['glucose']));
                }
                print(chartData.length);
                return Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "رسم بياني لمستويات الضغط خلال اسبوع",
                        style: textStyle2,
                      ),
                      Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        child: SfCartesianChart(
                            plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                              maximumLabelWidth: 80,
                            ),
                            primaryYAxis: CategoryAxis(
                              maximumLabelWidth: 80,
                            ),
                            enableAxisAnimation: true,
                            // borderColor: yellow,
                            series: <CartesianSeries<ChartData, dynamic>>[
                              ColumnSeries<ChartData, dynamic>(
                                color: yellow,
                                dataSource: chartData,
                                xAxisName: "days",
                                yAxisName: "values",
                                // color: yellow,
                                animationDuration: 20,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData gelu, _) =>
                                    gelu.xValue,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData gelu, _) =>
                                    gelu.yValue,
                              )
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              });
        }));
```

}
}

```
class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.xValue, this.yValue);
  String xValue;
  double yValue;
}
```

here is my output which give me only the information of the first document please if any one could give me the solution

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future getElderlyId() async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
          .get()
          .then((data) {
        setState(() {
          elderlyId = data.data()['elderlyId'];
        });
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('glucose')
                .where('uid', isEqualTo: elderlyId)
                .snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // return Center(
                //   child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                // );

                List<ChartData> chartData = [];
                for (int index = 0;
                    index < snapshot.data.docs.length;
                    index++) {
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                  chartData.add(ChartData.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data()));
                }

                return Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "رسم بياني لمستويات السكر خلال اسبوع",
                        style: textStyle2,
                      ),
                      Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                        child: SfCartesianChart(
                            plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            // primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                            //   maximumLabelWidth: 80,
                            // ),
                            primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
                                // Interval type will be months
                                intervalType: DateTimeIntervalType.days,
                                interval: 1),
                            primaryYAxis: CategoryAxis(
                              maximumLabelWidth: 80,
                            ),
                            enableAxisAnimation: true,
                            // borderColor: yellow,
                            series: <CartesianSeries<ChartData, dynamic>>[
                              ColumnSeries<ChartData, dynamic>(
                                color: yellow,
                                dataSource: chartData,
                                xAxisName: "days",
                                yAxisName: "values",
                                // color: yellow,
                                animationDuration: 20,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData gelu, _) =>
                                    gelu.xValue,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData gelu, _) =>
                                    gelu.yValue,
                              )
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }));
  }
}

class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.xValue, this.yValue);
  ChartData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> dataMap)
      : xValue = dataMap['date'],
        yValue = dataMap['glucose'];
  Timestamp xValue;
  double yValue;
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! as I wanted thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a User of Syncfusion_charts here.

The error is mostly due from your xValue, because they are actually `String` and in your chart, you classify them as a `CategoryAxis`.
So since they are the same `String`, it make only one value.

One solution could be:

Update your Firebase Back-End so it can take `DateTime` and not `String` in your document.
To update your xValue so it can be a `DateTime`.

```dart
class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.xValue, this.yValue);
  DateTime xValue;
  double yValue;
}
```

Then, use a [DateTimeAxis](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-types#date-time-axis) or a [DateTimeCategoryAxis](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-types#date-time-category-axis) for your `primaryXAxis` in your chart.

Comment: any idea how to save the date in format  DateTime? when I do DateTime.now() it store it as timesTamp

Comment: You can save it as a String on your Back-End using `DateTime.now().toIso8601String()` then later use a `DateTime.tryParse()`

Comment: there is something wrong I did this  primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
                                    // Interval type will be months
                                    intervalType: DateTimeIntervalType.days,
                                    interval: 1), and I am not getting any column know

Comment: yes I updated to DateTime type , if u free to hepl can I contact you in Twitter

Comment: I retagged your post, syncfusion support is usually quick to answer questions on StackOverflow :)